# Adding/viewing attachments to features using only ArcGIS DEsktop Basic license level?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, fields-attributes, attachments, photos

Does anyone have an elegant solution to adding/viewing **[attachments](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000003vt000000.htm)**, like a table/photos for example from within ArcMap using only the ArcGIS basic license level?  Or any suggestions?

I'm looking for a way to deliver an .mxd or file geodatabase with features that are clickable and link to tables of info and photos.  The above feature of 10.0 is great; however I am limited by the license we have.

Comment: It's not nearly as elegant but have you investigated and ruled out Hyperlinks and HTML Popups?

Comment: That sounds like it might work, do you think it's possible to embed multiple photos, possibly even a little "gallery" of some sort, into the popup? I may have multiple photos for the same point/polygon feature. Thanks!

Comment: I'd look [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002r000000)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in our Comments, your best option appears to be to investigate **[HTML Popups](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002r000000)**.  If that does not meet your requirements perhaps edit your Question to further refine them by describing why not.

As an aside, and you are probably already aware of this, a Basic license allows you to view geodatabase attachments, but does not allow you to create them because that process involves creating/updating relationship classes in the background which requires Standard or Advanced licensing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to get your feet wet with .Net, you could [possibly do create attachments automatically from ArcObjects](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000001qr000000.htm).

The caveat at the bottom of the topic reads:

> Although ArcGIS Desktop users can use attachments from existing attachment tables with an ArcView license, creating attachment tables in an ArcSDE geodatabase requires an ArcEditor license. Likewise, ArcGIS Engine users can use the majority of functionality described in this topic with the Engine Runtime, but require the Geodatabase Update extension to create attachment tables in ArcSDE geodatabases.

which implies to me that you can still create attachments in File Geodatabases, just not SDE.